# How to stop my tokio thread from blocking

Tags: rust, unix-socket, rust-tokio

I am writing a client for a Unix Domain Socket, which should listen for messages from a server, I got it to work after hours of researching (it shows 1-2 messages), but after that tokio crashes with the error: `Error: Kind(WouldBlock)`, here is my code:

```rust
use std::env::{var, VarError};
use std::io::{self, Write};
use tokio::net::UnixStream;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let hypr_instance_sig = match var("HYPRLAND_INSTANCE_SIGNATURE") {
        Ok(var) => var,
        Err(VarError::NotPresent) => panic!("Is hyprland running?"),
        Err(VarError::NotUnicode(_)) => panic!("wtf no unicode?"),
    };

    let socket_path = format!("/tmp/hypr/{hypr_instance_sig}/.socket2.sock");

    let stream = UnixStream::connect(socket_path).await?;

    loop {
        stream.readable().await?;

        let mut buf = [0; 4096];
        stream.try_read(&mut buf)?;
        io::stdout().lock().write_all(&buf)?;
    }
}
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: If you want to use `try_read`, you need to ignore `WouldBlock` errors as shown in the [example for `try_read`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/net/struct.UnixStream.html#method.try_read). Though you may be better served by `read`, which is available through `AsyncReadExt`. Also, your buffer isn't guaranteed to be full after `try_read` or `read`, you need to check the return value and then only `write_all` as many bytes as were read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fully agree with @Caesar's comment.

- don't use `try_read`, use `read` instead
- slice the buffer to the correct size after reading
- check for `0` bytes read, which indicates that the end of the stream was reached

```
use std::env::{var, VarError};
use std::io::{self, Write};
use tokio::io::AsyncReadExt;
use tokio::net::UnixStream;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let hypr_instance_sig = match var("HYPRLAND_INSTANCE_SIGNATURE") {
        Ok(var) => var,
        Err(VarError::NotPresent) => panic!("Is hyprland running?"),
        Err(VarError::NotUnicode(_)) => panic!("wtf no unicode?"),
    };

    let socket_path = format!("/tmp/hypr/{hypr_instance_sig}/.socket2.sock");

    let mut stream = UnixStream::connect(socket_path).await?;

    let mut buf = [0; 4096];

    loop {
        let num_read = stream.read(&mut buf).await?;
        if num_read == 0 {
            break;
        }
        let buf = &buf[..num_read];
        io::stdout().lock().write_all(buf)?;
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I didn't test the code because I don't have the required socket file. It compiles, though.